# Bug ou erro de lógica

Tags: php

Olá, estou resolvendo uma questão que é uma rotina na minha vida, pegar csv e popular banco de dados.

Peguei uma demanda onde preciso pegar as 21 primeiras colunas de 32 arquivos csv e agrupar tudo em uma única tabela, usei o seguinte:

```
    ini_set('memory_limit', '60000M');

$path = '/var/www/html/csv/';

$files = array('ACELERA2.csv','ATLAS.csv','BOLSA.csv','CADASTRO_DMA.csv','CADASTRO_INFRA.csv','CAPITAL.csv','CHEGAMAIS.csv','CPMF.csv','ECOOL.csv','ENERGIA.csv','ENQUADRAMENTO.csv','INOVACAO.csv','INTELIGENCIA.csv','JUROS.csv','MEU_NOVO_MUNDO.csv','MONITOR.csv','NEXCODE.csv','PESQUISAEXPORTACAO.csv','PREMIO_AGUA.csv','PREMIO_MERITO.csv','PROTHEUS.csv','RM.csv','RODADAS.csv','SCE.csv','SCN.csv','SCS.csv','SGC.csv','SINDI.csv','SMS.csv','SPVNE.csv','SR.csv' );

$insert = null;

foreach ($files as $file ) 
{
    $rrow = null;



    $fp = fopen($path.$file, "r");

    if ($fp) 
    {
        $head = fgetcsv($fp, 0, ";", '"');

        $count = count($head);

        $collun = '(';

        //$collun ='CREATE TABLE '.substr($file,0,-4).' ('."\r\n";

        for ($i=0; $i < 22; $i++) { 

            if ( $i !== $count )
            {
                $collun.= $head[$i].',';
            }
        }

        $collun_ = substr($collun,0,-1).')';

        while ( $data = fgetcsv($fp, 0, ";",'"') ) 
        {

            $row = '(';

            for ($i=0; $i < 22; $i++) 
            { 
                if ( $data[$i] == null ) 
                {
                    $insert = 'null';
                }
                else
                {
                    $insert = $data[$i];
                }
                $row.= "$$".$insert."$$,";
            }

                $rrow.= substr($row,0,-1).')';

                $sql =  'INSERT INTO pf '.$collun_.' values '.$rrow.' ON CONFLICT (cpf) DO NOTHING';

                echo $sql;

                sleep(3);

                $dbconn = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=xxx user=xxxx password=xxxx")
                or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());

                $result = pg_query($dbconn, $sql);

                var_dump($result);

                pg_close($dbconn);              

        }

    }

}
```

O bug ocorre da seguinte forma, pra cada insert into ele add 3 conjuntos da variável $rrow não fechando a sintaxe corretamente. Agradeço quem puder colaborar.

Comment: Qual é a mensagem de erro?

Comment: O erro é que fica: insert into fp (...) Values (...) (...)(...); Sem a vírgula entre os valores, e nem queria o insert em bloco. O primeiro fiz em bloco é mesmo com 64gb ele não consegue alocar tudo.